# How to enable the mouse in C++ program under DOS using DJGPP?

Tags: c++, dos, djgpp

I've been using `DJGPP` for the first time recently and can't seem to enable mouse support. What's the best way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gosh, this takes me back! You need the software interrupt 33H - see http://www.sentex.net/~ajy/mouseint.html, and a tutorial of sorts at http://www.writeka.com/emage/mouse_events.html.

Comment: My best ever hack was to add mouse support for the hercules graphics mode of a commercial game, via int 33, by adding 8086 machine code to the executable using Borland's debugger. I remember feeling remarkably clever for the rest of that day.

Comment: Cool! Hercules graphics - cringe...that was my first pc, with 8088 clocked to turbo 12mhz with 10Mb hard drive and 5 quarter inch floppy 360K...happy memories...That's a neat hack you did there...

Comment: By the way, at the time, I knew it could display graphics, and had to put on a CGA emulator to play CGA games, until I came across Moraff's world which was beautiful under Hercules and ditched the CGA emulator  altogether...

Comment: int33h... I used it in QuickBasic applications to add mouse support... it was definitely cool at those times!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comprehensive list of Int 0x33 functions [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/ix/33/00.html). This is from the Ralph Brown's Interrupt List, which can be found [here](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm). Also here's a [link](http://www.pd.infn.it/www_cad/fanin/djgpp/manual6.html) to the mouse handler for DJGPP. Also, here's a link to the MSDOS programmer FAQ [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part4/), in which you will find the information about the mouse.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.